# Mysql query for joining three tables

Tags: mysql

I have three Tables.

***requests*** - request_id, request_message, requester_id

- ***requesters***
- requesters_id, requesters_name
- **responses**
- response_id, request_id, response_message

I want to fetch **All the fields from requests**, **requesters_name from requesters** for which requester_id is in requests table and **count of responses for request_id** from responses table.

please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT requests.*,requesters.requesters_name,count(1) AS c FROM requests
LEFT JOIN requesters ON requesters.requester_id = request.requester_id
LEFT JOIN responses ON responses.request_id = requests.request_id
GROUP BY requests.request_id
```

Comment: With Regular JOIN, if for any particular request there is no response, it will not show that row. but with left JOIN it will show that row with count = 0;

Comment: If there is a requester for every request, `INNER JOIN requesters` may be used.

Comment: Yes that will work. Because there is requester for each request. but response may or may not for each request. so we have to use LEFT JOIn for that

Answer (score 0):

I'd get the count from a sub-select and just join the other two tables together with a regular join

```
SELECT r.*, rn.requesters_name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(response_id) 
       FROM responses rp WHERE r.request_id=rp.request_id) 
    AS response_count
FROM requests r JOIN requester rn ON r.requesters_id=rn.requesters_id
```

Comment: in the second response to this question, we can avoid subquery

Comment: LEFT JOIN and GROUP are slower